# Why Won't External Display Work in 18.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, thunderbolt

I'm using a Dell XPS-13-9360 laptop (no external drivers needed or detected, according to Ubuntu), connected to a TV through a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter. I'm getting sound through the HDMI cable, but the TV still says no input. I've tried Wayland and Xorg, and when I open Screen Display settings, the TV is detected, but nothing shows up on it, whether I try to join the displays, mirror them or set it to ONLY TV. I've tried rebooting, too, but no go. What can I do to get this working?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Les.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't determine the supported resolution when sending output to HDMI, so you will have to make sure that when sending HDMI signal to TV, the resolution is supported by the TV. Try `1920x1080 60Hz`, most TV supports that.